# не маштабируется фон

Tags: css3, html5

у меня есть код:

```
   .fst-block{
        background-size: 1700px;
        margin: -160px auto 0;
        height: 981px;
        width: 1900px;
        background: url("../img/background.png") no-repeat;
        background-position-x: 0;

    }
```

мне нужно чтобы он был смещен влево, а он не шевелиться.
помогите пожалуйста.

```
html{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1511px;
}
.icon-head{
    background: url("../img/menu-1.png") no-repeat;
    width: 92px;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h2{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.text-bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu-item-alergy-img{
    background: url("../img/hribok-1.png") no-repeat;
    width: 188px;
    height: 191px;
}
.flex{
    display: flex;
}
.text-right-img{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 19px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.txt-und-img::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #becbd8;
    margin:  31px 0 20px 0;
}
.sec-bloc-menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 26px;
}
.statistica{
    background: url("../img/stat.png") no-repeat;
    width: 1170px;
    height: 153px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.text-statistica{
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 60px;
}
.thr-block{
    width: 1511px;
    height: 1192px;
    background: url("../img/thr-back.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 141px;
}
.thr-icon-head{
    background: no-repeat url("../img/menu-1.png");
    width: 92px;
    height: 65px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.h2-thr{
    font-size: 48px;
}
.thr-block-menu-item{
    width: 392px;
    height: 631px;
    background: url("../img/thr-block-fst.png") no-repeat;
}
.menu-item-top-text{
    padding-top: 95px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.menu-item-under-top-text{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu-item-under-scobka{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 60px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #ff6b00;
}
.menu-item-bottom-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 19px 42px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
.thr-block-menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.thr-block-menu-item-sec{
    width: 392px;
    height: 631px;
    background: url("../img/thr-block-sec.png") no-repeat;
}
.thr-block-menu-item-thr{
    width: 392px;
    height: 631px;
    background: url("../img/thr-block-thir.png") no-repeat;
}
.thr-block-statistic{
    width: 1170px;
    height: 165px;
    background: url("../img/vivod2.png") no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.thr-block-statistic-text{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 62px;
    font-size: 21px;
}
.fou-block-half-logo{
 width: 61px;
 background: url("../img/half-micocin.png") no-repeat;
 height: 59px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.fou-block-top-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.fou-block-mid-text{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 24px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.fou-block-menu-item{
    width: 370px;
    height: 352px;
    background: url("../img/fou-block-1.png") no-repeat;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.fou-block-menu-item-top-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 100px;
}
.fou-block-menu-item-bot-text{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -88px;
}
.fou-block-menu-item-sec{
    width: 370px;
    height: 394px;
    background: url("../img/fou-block-2.png") no-repeat;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding-top: 27px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.fou-block-menu-item-thr{
    width: 370px;
    height: 352px;
    background: url("../img/fou-block-3.png") no-repeat;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.fou-block-menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.fou-block-bot-menu{
    width: 917px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url("../img/zone-fou.png") no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.fou-block-bot-menu-text{
    font-size: 27px;
}
.fou-block-bot-menu-text span{
    color: #ff6b00;
}
.fif-block{
    width: 1505px;
    padding-top: 172px;
    height: 646px;
    background: url("../img/fif-block.png") no-repeat;
}
.fif-block-top-img{
    width: 92px;
    height: 65px;
    background: url("../img/menu-1.png") no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.fif-block-top-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 47px;
    margin: -27px;
}
.fif-block-top-text span{
    color: #ff6b00;
}
.fif-block-menu-center-img{
    width: 439px;
    height: 407px;
    background: url("../img/water.png") no-repeat;
    margin-top: 156px;
}
.fif-block-menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.fif-block-menu-menu-item-img{
    width: 135px;
    height: 135px;
    background: url("../img/top-img-1.png");
}
.fif-block-menu-menu-item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.fif-block-menu-menu-item-text{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 28px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.fif-block-menu-menu-item-text span{
    border-top: 3px solid #7bbf1c;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 43px;
}
.fif-block-menu-menu-item-img-sec{
    width: 135px;
    height: 135px;
    background: url("../img/top-block-2.png");
}
.fif-block-menu-menu-item-img-thr{
    width: 135px;
    height: 135px;
    background: url("../img/top-img-3.png");
}
.fst-block{
    background-size: 1700px;
    margin: -160px auto 0;
    height: 981px;
    width: 1900px;
    background: url("../img/background.png") no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 0;

}

.inf{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

весь код

Answer (score 0):

Задает начальное положение фонового изображения, установленного с помощью свойства background-image. В CSS3 допустимо указывать несколько значений для каждого фона, перечисляя значения через запятую.

Синтаксис
CSS2.1

```
background-position: [left | center | right | <проценты> | <значение>] || 
                     [top | center | bottom | <проценты> | <значение>] | inherit
```

CSS3

```
background-position: <позиция>[, <позиция>]*
```

Здесь:

<позиция> = [left | center | right | <проценты> | <значение>] || [top | center | bottom | <проценты> | <значение>] | inherit.

Значения

У свойства background-position два значения, положение по горизонтали (может быть — left, center, right) и вертикали (может быть — top, center, bottom). Кроме использования ключевых слов положение также можно задавать в процентах, пикселах или других единицах. Если применяются ключевые слова, то порядок их следования не имеет значения, при процентной записи вначале задается положение рисунка по горизонтали, а затем, через пробел, положение по вертикали. Отношение между используемыми ключевыми словами и процентной записью следующее:

```
top left = left top = 0% 0% (в левом верхнем углу)
top = top center = center top = 50% 0% (по центру вверху)
right top = top right = 100% 0% (в правом верхнем углу)
left = left center = center left = 0% 50% (по левому краю и по центру)
center = center center = 50% 50% (по центру)
right = right center = center right = 100% 50% (по правому краю и по центру)
bottom left = left bottom = 0% 100% (в левом нижнем углу)
bottom = bottom center = center bottom = 50% 100% (по центру внизу)
bottom right = right bottom = 100% 100% (в правом нижнем углу)
В скобках указано, где располагается фоновый рисунок относительно контейнера.
```

При inherit значение наследуется у родителя элемента.

Пример:

```
background-image: url(images/mybg.png); /* Путь к фоновому рисунку */
background-position: right bottom; /* Положение фона */
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Отменяем повторение фона */
```

Источник: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position